# Adding char* variables together?

Tags: c, char

Very simple question but within my code I have two char* variables.

```
char* port = "1100";
char* ip = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr);
```

The first is a port number and the second tells the ip address of a given interface.

If I wanted to create a new variable say, char* both, why is it that I cannot say:

```
char* both = ip + port;
```

with the output of 172.21.8.179 1100? How can I get a new variable with that output? Thanks

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/

Comment: Do not add tags for different languages! C++ is not C.

Comment: And read what a _pointer_ is. You seem not even to have an idea about them. I'd recommend to read a C bokk or do a tutorial.

Comment: Because C doesn't have string types. You have to do that yourself, as well as doing the memory management.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to use snprintf

```
char buff[100];
snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%s %s", port, ip);
```

Comment: check your snprintf arguments

Comment: Taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut. What's wrong with strcpy here?

Comment: @Olaf You'd need a `strcpy` followed by two `strcat` to accomplish what the `snprintf` is doing. And using a sledgehammer to crack nuts will improve your arm strength, so it's a win-win :)

Comment: @user3386109: Yes, that is the attitude leading to GUIs with 16GiB requirement to run a text editor. Alone the format string parser is more bloat than the 10 strcpys. Also: it is just two memcpy and 1 strlen. And a modern compiler wil either inline them and use highly optimized code. If you are a brain-worker, there is nothing gained being a body-builder.

Comment: I expect that the OP doesnt want to simply add two stirng together. I suspect he is composing a string like "https://%s:%d", in that case snprintf is what he wants

Answer (score 0):

You can't add two strings in C because, well, they're not actually strings. They're just pointers. And adding two pointers results in a pointer that points at the address that is the sum of the two original addresses.

To concatenate two `char*`s together, you can use the [strcat(char * destination, const char * source)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) function. Just make sure that your `both` pointer is pointing to enough memory to actually hold the concatenated string!

Comment: "And adding two pointers results in a pointer that points at the address that is the sum of the two original addresses." - it's a constraint violation. Pointers aren't fancy integers

Comment: strings are not pointers.   They behave like pointers in some circumstances, but they are not pointers.

Comment: @Peter I think what he's trying to say that strings in C are implemented as an array of characters, and arrays are often managed using pointers to their first element. Therefore, you can't use `+` when concatenating strings because adding two pointers is meaningless. The wording can be tricky.

Comment: @M.M actually, a pointer is a variable that holds a value of an address which is a *fancy* **integer**, whoever downvoted this, tell me what's wrong with his answer? upvoted.

Comment: @KiraSama no an address isn't a fancy integer (in Standard C) . This is a common misconception that  contributes to the confusion newbies have surrounding pointers. If pointers were a sort of integer then you could add them, for example. But you can't. This answer claims two pointers can be added, which is false.

Comment: @M.M`A pointer is an address, which is a numeric value`
Incrementing a pointer results the next adjacent location in memory as `while(*ptr)ptr++;` when counting a length of an C string which the termination character at the end of it would be 0, stops the loop results the length of it is how much the loop iterated, so you're able to use arithmetic operations with pointers, never tried to add them cause It's meaningless but you **can**, unlike subtracting them which is useful in some ways, sorry if I didn't get your comment but I claim that I **can** add them && `printf` that integral address.

Comment: @KiraSama The compiler will give an error for attempting to add two pointers. And/or you could read the C Standard

Comment: @M.M Just cast `(int)` before them and their addresses would be added.

Comment: @KiraSama The cast changes a pointer value to an integer value. Integers can be added, pointers can't. Also, your cast may cause undefined behaviour on a system with 64-bit pointers and 32-bit ints.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sprintf()` function call

**...**

`sprintf(char * buffer, const char * format, ...)`

**Dynamic**

```
char* res = (char*)malloc(15);
char* str1 = "Hello ";
char* str2 = "World!";
sprintf(res, "%s%s", str1, str2);
puts(res); // Hello World!
```

**Static**

```
char res[15];
char str1[] = "Hello ";
char str2[] = "World!";
sprintf(res, "%s%s", str1, str2);
puts(res); // Hello World!
```

you're able to add integers into a **C** string too with the `%d` format specifier.